# How would we solve the following logic problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

"Let us introduce a new logical connective ∗, which we define
with the following truth table.

[image]

The sentence P ∨ ¬Q is logically equivalent to

(((P ∗ P) ∗ Q) ∗ ((P ∗ P) ∗ Q)) ∗ (((P ∗ P) ∗ Q) ∗ ((P ∗ P) ∗ Q)).

Find a sentence written only with parentheses, ∗, and the proposition letters X and Y , which is logically equivalent to

¬(X ⇒ (¬X ∨ ¬Y )).

Prove that your answer is correct."

So I think my first main problem is finding what * is, but after investigating, it does not seem to be either of "and", "or" or "implies". After this, I sort of hit a dead end.

Any help on what the * could be, and then forming a sentence with the * to get the final sentence?

Comment: $*$ is NAND, this gate is universal (like the NOR one) in the sense that you can build any circuit out of it.

Comment: You could start by simplifying $\neg (X \implies (\neg X \vee \neg Y))$ using rules such as De Morgan's laws.  The * operator does have a name, but be warned that I don't think knowing it or reading about it will help you solve this problem faster. The name is "nand," short for "not and".

Answer (score 1):

First let's reduce expression :

$\lnot(X\implies(\lnot X\lor \lnot Y)) = \lnot(\lnot X\lor(\lnot X\lor \lnot Y)) = X\land(X\land Y) = X\land Y$

Then we convert to NAND :

$X\land Y=\lnot(X*Y)=1*(X*Y)\qquad$ variant : $(X*Y)*(X*Y)$

*Note: NAND is usually noted $A\uparrow B$.*

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that when $P$ and $Q$ are both true, then $P * Q$ is false, and when $P$ and $Q$ are both false, then $P *Q$ is true.  This tells us that:

$$P*P = \neg P$$

Next, the truth-table looks a bit like the table for the $\lor$ ... it's just upside down ...  aha!

$$P*Q = \neg P \lor \neg Q$$

OK, now let's take your expression and do a bit of known algebra:

$$\neg(X \rightarrow (\neg X \lor \neg Y)) =$$

$$\neg(\neg X \lor (\neg X \lor \neg Y)) = $$

$$\neg(\neg X \lor \neg X \lor \neg Y) = $$

$$\neg(\neg X \lor \neg Y)$$

Oooh!  we have a $\neg$, and we have a $\neg X \lor \neg Y$!.. So we get:

$$\neg(\neg X \lor \neg Y)$$

$$\neg X*Y = $$

$$(X * Y) * (X * Y)$$

Comment: good you managed to write vertically what I wrote horizontally. :p

Comment: @zwim Yeah, pretty much!  I was thinking of the $\lor$, rather than the NAND ...